# What's the correct pattern of setting multiple properties, each triggering expensive refresh operations?

Tags: design-patterns, gwt, optimization, user-interface, widget

Suppose you have an user interface widget, and on some status change, you need to set perform some actions.
So you do something like:

```
widget.setSize(400, 300);
widget.setHeader("whatever");
widget.setData(new int[] {2, 3, 5});
widget.setFancyThingEnabled(true);
```

Then suppose each of these operations triggers a whole refresh of the widget. That's inefficient.

I know several ways to fix this, but what's the correct/best/most elegant pattern to do it?
I know I could:

- create some `Property` object, that I can fill in and then give to the widget.
- have some `setRefresh(enabled:boolean)` method, to wrap a transaction.
- allow property settings only through a callback method, which will then be executed inside a transaction.
- put refreshes on a queue and wait for a little while before proceeding.

I'm working with GWT, which runs on a browser on an arbitrarily slow machine, but this applies to almost any environment.

**Edit:**
Keep in mind that the UI is an example, I'm referring about the general scenario in which the transition from a state to another state triggers too much unnecessary computation on each other intermediate state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

```
widget
  .startAction() // instance of WidgetAction returned
  .setSize(400, 300)
  .setHeader("whatever")
  .setData(new int[] {2, 3, 5})
  .setFancyThingEnabled(true)
  .close(); // actual changes made for UI
```

Comment: I like the answer, but I would not call that a Strategy pattern at all.  That type of chained method invocation is typical of a fluent interface or fluent builder (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: WidgetAction is a "strategy", which the way its methods are called is called "fluent interface"

Comment: I gave you a +1, but I still disagree.  Strategy = "Define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable.  Strategy lets the alogorithm vary independently from client that use it".  Stratgey is about being able swap in different alogorithms without the clinet code needing to change (typical example being swapping in zlib for zip compression by creating a compression strategy object).  I don't see that swapping concept used or needed in your answer.

Comment: `WidgetAction` is an interface. Its concrete implementation will provide certain "algorithm" of a widget refreshing. `widget` will make a decision with algorithm to use.

Comment: That's another solution to implement a transaction, in case you're already using method chaining. My concern about this kind of solution is that it doesn't enforce itself: what happens if I forget to call `close()`?

Comment: I think it is an elegant way to provide the transaction.  If implemented properly it should provide a better solutiuon than simply setting Refresh = false, do a bunch of stuff, then Refresh = true because it should be all or nothing.  If you don't call close() then none of the interum steps should be applied either.  The alternative version of Refresh = false, makes changes, Refresh = true is nore suseptible to errors because you can get partial updates to your widget in the face of coding or execution error that makes you miss the Refresh = true.

Comment: @yegor We will have to agree to disgree on the strategy topic :)

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessary, because the browser is already doing this for you. This is possible, because rendering doesn't have to occur until the entire current JavaScript event handler is finished. It's actually a great advantage of web development compared to some desktop GUI frameworks.

Comment: I agree in simple scenarios, but this is not true in my case. I'm working with chart libraries which are not flexible, and I have to reinstantiate them everytime I change anything. This involves creating new DOM nodes, make calculations and then call draw methods on canvases. Whether the canvases are then displayed or not makes little difference, as I have a couple of seconds of unresponsive time anyway.

Comment: @djjeck: Your comment seems to change the original question completely  (maybe it should be adjusted?)